# Javascript exporting the phrase that has been hyperlinked

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

Currently trying to make a script to:

1. Search through a pdf file
2. Find all links inside of said file
3. Output these links to an excel file

I am having an issue to how they are getting exported. I want the excel file to have different columns stating

- The file it came from
- Author
- Link phrase
- The actual link.

However with my current code I'm not sure how I would adapt it to include the phrase that has held said link. This is what my excel file looks like:

[image: Excel file]

Here is the Javascript code (I want to be able to Export the phrases within the PDFs such as where the links come from)

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const PDFExtract = require("pdf.js-extract").PDFExtract;
const excelJS = require("exceljs");
const dirname = path.resolve(__dirname);

const pdfExtract = new PDFExtract();

const options = {
    disableCombineTextItems: false,
    normalizeWhitespace: true,
};

async function exportExcell(links, fileName, author) {
    const workbook = new excelJS.Workbook(); // Create a new workbook
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Links Extract"); // New Worksheet
    // Column for data in excel. key must match data key
    worksheet.columns = [
        { header: "S no.", key: "s_no", width: 10 },
        { header: "File Name", key: "fileName", width: 30 },
        { header: "Author", key: "author", width: 30 },
        { header: "Links", key: "link", width: 70 },
    ];

    let row = {
        s_no: 1,
        fileName,
        author,
        link: links[0],
    };
    worksheet.addRow(row);

    // Looping through links
    for (let i = 1; i < links.length; i++) {
        row = {
            s_no: i + 1,
            fileName: "",
            author: "",
            link: links[i],
        };
        worksheet.addRow(row);
    }

    // Making first line in excel bold
    worksheet.getRow(1).eachCell((cell) => {
        cell.font = { bold: true };
    });
    try {
        const name = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - 4);
        const fileWrite = path.join(dirname + `/files/output/${name}_extract_links.xlsx`);
        const data = await workbook.xlsx
            .writeFile(fileWrite)
            .then(() => console.log("file successfully created excel file"));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

async function renderPdf(buffer, fileName) {
    return pdfExtract.extractBuffer(buffer, options, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        // console.dir(Object.keys(data));
        let links = new Set();
        data.pages.forEach((page) => {
            if (page.links.length > 0) {
                page.links.forEach((link) => {
                    links.add(link);
                });
            }
        });
        const arrLinks = Array.from(links);
        return exportExcell(arrLinks, fileName, data.meta.info.Author);
    });
}

function readFileAsync() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            fs.readdirSync(path.join(dirname, "/files/uploads"), {
                withFileTypes: true,
            })
                .filter(
                    (file) =>
                        file.isFile() &&
                        file.name.toLowerCase().includes(".pdf") &&
                        !file.name.includes(".swp")
                )
                .forEach(async (template) => {
                    const fileName = template.name;
                    const fileToRead = path.join(dirname + `/files/uploads/${fileName}`);
                    fs.readFile(fileToRead, async function (err, buffer) {
                        const doc = renderPdf(buffer, fileName);
                        //console.log(doc)
                    });
                });
            resolve({ data: "success reading files" });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error line 508", e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

// Execute when user select a file
const onFileSelected = async () => {
    await readFileAsync();
};

onFileSelected();
```

Comment: @KJ i believe in this case it was turned into an external link, when hovering the phrase it holds a completely different link if thats what you mean?

Comment: @KJ i see, https://www.citi.com/citi/suppliers/data/Citi_Requirements_for_Suppliers_English.pdf?ieNocache=306 is the pdf, not sure if that is able to answer the question/statement being presented? Just wondering how easy it would be to find these phrases and export them

Comment: Thank you very much, im just wondering how possible it would be to output the different underlined hyperlinked phrases to export them to the excel file

Comment: I see so in this case it would almost be too complex to try to grab all of this type of information from the pdf in javascript? my knowledge of javascript is slim so im unaware